# Using images on HTMLs, loaded/inserted into an Outlook 2013 Email?

Tags: html, email, outlook

I'm creating a responsive email template using HTML, and I have a banner on the template. I'm able to see the image on my local machine, however sending it to someone else makes the image 'unloadable'.

I understand this since the image is saved on my local machine, and I've tried uploading the image to a hosting service (Google Photos) and adding that to the code yet it still doesn't work.

How can I pull this off? Is there a way to upload a photo, and reference it on a HTML code inserted into a Outlook 2013 email? is there a different photo hosting service that I could use?

Answer (score 0):

You should load this to a server from where the email is coming from so it looks legit. If this is for a client then use their server.